# Error "no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present" when create thumbnail with dropzone js from amazon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, dropzone.js

I'm developing a rails application, I'm using amazon to host my site's images and I use dropzone to handle the upload. When I edit an insertion, I'd like to see the images that this insertion already have, and display them in the dropzone preview. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server) with some modification due to the new api of dropzone 5.0
this is my code

```
drop_zone = new Dropzone '#drag_drop_img_edit', {
  url: '/insertions/upload'
  autoProcessQueue: false
  uploadMultiple: true
  maxFilesize: 2
  addRemoveLinks: true
  parallelUploads: 10
  maxFiles: 5
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*'
  paramName: 'file'
  successmultiple: (data, response) ->
    $('#directory_up').val(response.directory)
    $('#edit-insertion').off('submit').submit();
  init: ->
    myDropzone = this;
    this.on("removedfile", (file) ->
      removedfiles.push(file)
      console.log(file)
      i = myDropzone.files .indexOf(file);
      if(i != -1)
        myDropzone.files .splice(i, 1);
    )

    this.on("addedfile", (file) ->

      if (myDropzone.files.length)
        len = this.files.length
        myfun = ->
          if(myDropzone.files[_i].name == file.name)
            myDropzone.removeFile(file)
        myfun() for _i in [0...len-1]

      defaultRadioButton = Dropzone.createElement(
        '<div class="default_pic_container"><input type="radio" name="first_pic" value="'+file.name+'" /> Set Principal</div>');
      file.previewElement.appendChild(defaultRadioButton);
    )
    $("#edit-insertion-btn").on 'click', (e) ->
      s = JSON.stringify(removedfiles)
      $('#deleted_image').val(s)
      $('#first_img').val($('input[name=first_pic]:checked').val())
      if myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length >  0
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
      else
        console.log('shalla')
  params: {
    'authenticity_token': AUTH_TOKEN

  }

}

//HERE I TAKE THE INFORMATIONS ABOUT THE IMAGES OF THE INSERTION, AND I ADD THEM IN MY DROPZONE VIEW
my_array = JSON.parse($('#my-images').val())
console.log(my_array)
addToDropZone = (file, index) ->
  mock = { name: file.name, size: 12345, accepted: true, dataURL: file.url}
  #console.log(mock.url)
  drop_zone.emit("addedfile", mock)
  console.log(mock.dataURL)
  // this is the new api
  drop_zone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mock, drop_zone.options.thumbnailWidth,
    drop_zone.options.thumbnailHeight,
    drop_zone.options.thumbnailMethod, true, (thumbnail) ->
      drop_zone.emit('thumbnail', mock, thumbnail)
      drop_zone.emit("complete", mock)
      drop_zone.files.push(mock)
      if (index == parseInt($('#first_img_index').val()))
        s = "input[value='"
        s += mock.name
        s += "']"
        $(s).prop('checked', true)
  ,'anonymous') // added anonymous due to cross origin

#drop_zone.options.maxFiles = drop_zone.options.maxFiles - 1
addToDropZone(my_array[i], i) for i in [0...my_array.length]
```

In development I upload the picture on my computer and in production I upload them on amazon s3 bucket. In development everything works great and the thumbnails are generated, but in production I can't see the thumbnails of the images that are alredy in the server. In the console I get this message

```
Access to Image at 'http://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bookmarket-assets/oni.jpg?1505901043' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I also configured the CORS on my bucket, this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

How can I avoid this error ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close. Based on what you are showing I am guessing that the method used is not a GET. So you would need to add the method your client uses.

Fire up a developer console in your browser and look at the calls that are made. I am guessing you would need OPTIONS and POST to make this work, but this depends on how dropzone actually does this under the covers.